# Loading post like facebook on scrool to bottom

Tags: pagination, ajax

I have a page to show my product, now i want to load further posts using "infinite scroll".

Comment: "loading post like facebook"?.. How is your page set up? What existing solutions have you researched and tried?

Comment: Yeah, the question is terribly phrased, but I think the OP is looking for "infinite scroll".

Answer (score 1):

Search for `Infinite scroll`. There are also WordPress plugins created for that purpose.